# Angular 6 Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with “exportAs” set to “matMenu”

Tags: angular6

I do have below code for adding mat button logic in our application, What's wrong with this code:? I added all the related mat module needed for the application in app module.

```
 <button mat-icon-button matMenuTriggerFor="menu">
        {{selectedValue}}  <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
            <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
                <li class="mat-tree-node">
                    <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
                    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
                    <button mat-button (click)="myClickFunction(node.name)">
                        {{node.name}}
                    </button>
                </li>
            </mat-tree-node>
            <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
            <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
                <li>
                    <div class="mat-tree-node">
                        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                                {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                            </mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button mat-button (click)="myClickFunction(node.name)">
                            {{node.name}}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
                        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </mat-nested-tree-node>
        </mat-tree>
    </mat-menu>
```

I get this error:

```
compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("
        {{selectedValue}}  <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu [ERROR ->]#menu="matMenu">
        <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="exam"): ng:///ComponentsModule/TabularTreeComponent.html@32:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Please register MatMenuModule in your RootModule

```
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material';

imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 MatMenuModule
]
```

Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-u5odez?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)